# How can I remove the shadow on the markers on my map?

Tags: java, android, google-maps, overlay, android-mapview

I am displaying a custom marker on my Google Map. They are placed fine, but they have this funny shadow. How can I remove the shadow?[image]

```
@Override
        public boolean draw(Canvas canvas, MapView mapView, boolean shadow, long when) {
            super.draw(canvas, mapView, shadow);

            // ---translate the GeoPoint to screen pixels---
            Point screenPts = new Point();
            mapView.getProjection().toPixels(geoPnt, screenPts);

            // ---add the marker---
            /*Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.pushpin);
            canvas.drawBitmap(bmp, screenPts.x, screenPts.y - 67, null);*/
            return true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: show us the code you use to display the map

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd try to pass `false` for the `shadow` parameter when invoking the overridden method.

That means it should look like `super.draw(canvas, mapView, false)`.

Comment: even when set to false they appear

Comment: @Sheehan Alam: This is the way it is supposed to work. Maybe the push-pin drawable is like that?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
@Override
    public boolean draw(Canvas canvas, MapView mapView, boolean shadow, long when) {
      if (!shadow) {
        super.draw(canvas, mapView, shadow);

        // ---translate the GeoPoint to screen pixels---
        Point screenPts = new Point();
        mapView.getProjection().toPixels(geoPnt, screenPts);

        // ---add the marker---
        Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.pushpin);
        canvas.drawBitmap(bmp, screenPts.x, screenPts.y - 67, null);
      }
      return true;
    }
}
```